# typeOrm - js syntax - define composite unique constraint

Tags: javascript, typeorm

I'm using typeOrm in a js project.
I want to create a composite unique constraint for my entity, and cannot figure out the js syntax for that (the [ts syntax](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/unique) is clear)

can someone help?

another thing - since the [js syntax reference](https://github.com/typeorm/javascript-example/blob/master/src/app1-es5/entity/Post.js) is kind of barebones (which is expected, after all this seems to be typescript oriented as the name implies), i assume i will face these "how do i do this in js syntax" issues quite a lot - should i ditch typeOrm and switch to sequelize/prisma/some other native js orm?

i'm coming from a Java background and this is a toy project - i chose typeOrm since it feels like JPA, but maybe that was a mistake...

thanks,
Tomer

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't use TypeScript it helps to take a look at the types.
Here [GitHub TypeORM EntitySchemaOptions](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/beea2e1e4429d13d7864ebc23aa6e58fa01647ea/src/entity-schema/EntitySchemaOptions.ts) you can see which options you have, when creating a new EntitySchema.  And [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/beea2e1e4429d13d7864ebc23aa6e58fa01647ea/src/entity-schema/EntitySchemaUniqueOptions.ts) you can see how you use uniques.

An example would be:

```
new EntitySchema({
     name: "Example",
     columns: {
       id: {
         primary: true,
         type: Number
       },
       name: {
         type: "varchar"
       },
       title: {
         type: "varchar"
       }
     },
     uniques: [
       {
         columns: ['name', 'title']
       }
     ]
})
```

---

To your second question:
In your case I would use TypeORM with TypeScript. Especially if you're coming from a Java background the type safety would be great.